# Bitcoin exchange platforms and foreign exchange regulations

Tags: exchanges, regulation

I'm wondering how cryptocurrency exchange platform adapt to country regulations where foreign exchange is forbidden (especially where sending money outside is forbidden).

How they could buy Bitcoin from outside without violating regulations (foreign exchange regulations), in the case if they don't have much liquidity to match international market price of Bitcoin ?

Answer (score 1):

There's basically no way to answer this in a way that's general to countries that forbid foreign exchange, because these regulations have different goals in different countries.

For example, in Venezuela, all foreign exchanges must go through a state bank. The purpose of this is so that they can pretend that their currency is worth more than it actually is. If the central bank in Venezuela doesn't deal in the currency of your choice, I don't think you have any sort of recourse.

I don't have any advice for you, besides, "Hire the nephew of the guy who runs the central bank in your country."

Answer (score 1):

Illegal exchange flourishes wherever exchange is forbidden.

Legal exchange operates to the degree and magnitude of effective enforcement of the ban.

Tracking goods & services trade paid in a cryptocurrency would be difficult, so trade would be the only way in an area that effectively restricts a cryptocurrency's trade with other currencies.